# allow to use geolocation for a website for which I previously refused it

Tags: google-chrome, browser, geolocation

Once I refused a website to get my geolocation info, but right now I would like it to do this. How can I allow this?

I tried to find it in webbrowser settings, but with no success.

Basically I need this for Chrome, but I would be nice (for other users) to see a solution for other browsers.

Comment: In Chrome you can go to chrome://chrome/settings/contentExceptions#location . To get to this manually, go Settings, Show advanced, Content Settings, Location, Manage Exceptions

Comment: Try this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 should show you a location denied icon to the right of the address bar, which when clicked will show you clear options.

Alternatively you can find the setting under settings->advanced->content settings->location->manage exceptions

Answer (score 2):

Just use this cool instructions. I hope it will be useful.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en

[image]