# In-browser geolocation feature: how can I prompt the user to reenable after they've denied it?

Tags: browser, geolocation

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370203/allow-to-use-geolocation-for-a-website-for-which-i-previously-refused-it), but in my case I am the web developer. How can I get the browser to ask the user again if they want to allow geolocation?  I was hoping I could put some text in the page, something like, *"This page's features are only available when geolocation services are active, but you have denied them for this site. Click here to try again."*

I know how to change the browser to accept this, but how do I help the visitors to the page from any browser to simply turn it on at the click of a button.

Comment: I think the [Browser remembers the users decision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353909/make-html5-geolocation-ask-permission-every-time-user-reloads-the-page) so you could either tell the person how to reset their browser for that page. Or you could make a little popup that asks if they want the location to be used. If they do then the browser will prompt them.

Comment: @Noah, Thats my question. How do i get the browser to prompt them again?

Comment: Ik, It looks like a lot of web browsers remember the fact that the user denied location permission. So I do not think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions). Unfortunately at the moment it only allows to get the status of a permission, and mandatory requesting a permission for given API is not supported in any browser.