# Ionic serve & Node.js simple web server can't bypass Chrome geolocation blocking

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-chrome, ionic-framework, geolocation

Chrome blocks tracking location and therefore my app doesn't work when I run`ionic serve`. I've tried to get around it with the following to no avail.

There were some answers saying to get around it by installing a simple node.js server as chrome will block local files, so I ran:

```
sudo npm install http-server -g
http-server -o --cors
```

Then I went to http://localhost:8080/www/index.html which pulled up my app.

Went to chrome settings -> advanced -> content settings -> manage exceptions -> hostname pattern: http://localhost:8080/www/index.html, Behavior: Allow

I made sure to do the ^ so chrome also allowed http://127.0.0.1:8080/www/index.html.

None of this is working, chrome is still blocking geolocation.

Answers I looked at and tried to get to this point: [HTML 5 Geo Location Prompt in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423938/html-5-geo-location-prompt-in-chrome), [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server%E2%80%8B), [allow to use geolocation for a website for which I previously refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370203/allow-to-use-geolocation-for-a-website-for-which-i-previously-refused-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that firefox doesn't block geolocation the way chrome does and works well with ionic serve.